# SharePoint Management Shell is missing on Workflow Manager Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

All...

I have installed SP2013 / Workflow Manager in a 4 server farm following a deployment pattern from series of videos at the following URL - "...technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn201724..."
The installation / configuration steps are consistent with those detailed at "...blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/..."

1. The AD / DNS Server is up and properly configured,
2. The SQL Server 2014 setup is configured and running,
3. The SharePoint 2013 platform is installed and the Farm is configured, under Central Administration I can see / create Sites
4. The Workflow Manager is installed and I can access the URL on the local WF server

   [image]

Here is where things break down...
The steps for **Install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server 2013** on the above URLs as well as here "msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588", All indicate the following steps as a requirement -

To configure Workflow Manager on a server that is part of the SharePoint 2013 farm and on which communication takes place by using HTTP

1. Log on to the computer in the SharePoint Server 2013 farm where Workflow Manager was installed.
2. Open the SharePoint Management Shell as an administrator. This is
   accomplished by right-clicking the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell
   and choosing Run as administrator.
3. Run the Register-SPWorkflowService cmdlet.

The problem is that the Workflow Server does not have the SharePoint Management Shell installed...  I have tried to use PowerShell to include the PSSnapin based on a reference from my research but there is an issue that arises here as well...
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

How can I complete the install or how can I get the SharePoint Management Shell installed on the Workflow Server?
I appreciate in advance any/all suggestions/guidance/assistance.
Oh, did I mention that I am not a Server Administrator so please bear with me and my neediness...
Joemac

Answer (score 1):

All...

I have uncovered my answer -

The Microsoft documentation states...

1.Log on to the computer in the SharePoint Server 2013 farm where Workflow Manager was installed. (Extracted from "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588")

This statement is actually **incorrect** as well it is stated **incorrectly** if you are using the **video series** provided as your installation guide...

Watching that series, specifically Episode #5, the user is accessing the SharePoint Management Console to execute the Register cmdlet **AFTER** signing into the SharePoint Server ("sp.contoso.local") and **NOT** the server where the Workflow Manager is installed (re:Episode #3)...

This is what was throwing me for a loop because the instructions state to use the SharePoint Management Shell on the Workflow Server ("wf.contoso.local") to execute the command, but it is not installed there as an object.

A second "gotcha" for me was that when I executed the following **Register** cmdlet through the SharePoint Management Console from the SharePoint Server I received an error...

cmdlet - 
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://spxxxxx/sites/Workflow Demo" -WorkflowHostUri "http://wfxxxxx.xxxxxsp.com:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force

Error - 
Register-SPWorkflowService : Unable to connect to the remote service at http://wfxxxxx.com:12291/SharePoint/. See InnerException for more details.
Client ActivityId : ea68bfce-cb67-4b63-8ecb-973159fb5c8c.

Resolution - 
The issues was resolved through using the FQDN as the destination WorkflowHostUri...  Using the following cmdlet was successful...

Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://spxxxxx/sites/Workflow Demo" -WorkflowHostUri "http://wfxxxxx.xxxxxxsp.com:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force

I hope that my pain can assist others